# Remove directory from URL with

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am moving a Magento site from example.com/shopping to example.com and I have to 301 redirect all of the URLs to the new location (example.com). I am assuming I can use mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file to create a rewrite rule to do this? I tried to learn how to use mod_rewrite, but the syntax is so complex for me.

There are hundreds of pages that need to be redirected. Example:

```
http://www.example.com/shopping/product-category-1/product-sub-category.html
```

TO

```
http://www.example.com/product-category-1/product-sub-category.html
```

This is so that people don't end up with a 404 error when they enter the site via an old URL.

Comment: I'm literally going to have to do the same thing in a couple hours and my Google query was going to be something like `.htaccess redirect single page`. It turns up good examples, like [.htaccess 301 redirect of single page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1421068)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any rules you may already have there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shopping/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

If you want to redirect the browser so that the new URL appears in the location bar, add an `R` flag in square brackets:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shopping/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Ok, this is great advice, thank you. My next question would be: will this interfere with any other aspects of the default Magento .htaccess file?

Comment: @pbujok It will if magento expects there to be a `/shopping/` path in the URL, but it really depends on how you have it setup

Comment: Will the [L] part prevent other rewrites from running that may be necessary for the functionality of Magento? Would it be better to just include R=301 and let the rest of the rewrites run?

Comment: @pbujok The rewrite engine loops, so after that rule gets applied, the new URI (will be one without `/shopping/` in it) will go through all the rules again. The `L` just stops rewriting in the current iteration.

Comment: but to access admin, i can't use mysite.com/admin like earlier. Now i need to enter mysite.com/index.php/admin

Comment: For reference, in the case where `shopping` is a sub sub directory: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/shopping/(.*)$ $1/$2 [L,R=301]`