# How can I have redirect or make an alias for my websites directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, alias, web-hosting, mod-alias

**Real directory structure:**

http://example.com/directory1/directory2/directory3/hiddendirectory/directory4/

**I need the file to open as:**

http://example.com/hiddendirectory/directory4/

in the browser, but in reality the directory still be in the first location.

I am on shared hosting with hostgator and do not have full privileges so I cannot run any scripts.

I've done some research and I've messed around trying create an alias, but I can't get anything to work.

Here is what I put in the .htaccess file:

```
Alias /hiddendirectory/directory4 /directory1/directory2/directory3/hiddendirectory/directory4
```

But I always get a 500 server error. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove directory from URL with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668612/remove-directory-from-url-with)

Comment: Yeah I checked that out, unfortunately can't get anything functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Alias directive  runs on the Server config context not in htaccess.

In htaccess you can use mod_rewrite to rewrite your dirs.

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^hiddendir/dir4/?$ /dir1/dir2/dir3/hiddendir/dir4 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite

```
/hiddendir/dir4/
```

to

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/hiddendir/dir4
```

Comment: Thanks starkeen - tried your solution but now I'm getting a 404 error. Maybe I need to find place the Alias directive in the server config like you mentioned - /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf is correct file? Also for the alias directive will I need to change permissions or is my syntax good to go?

Comment: @David yes, your alias syntex is correct. Please read the manual for more info about **alias** and **aliasMatch** directive. 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html