# Remove subdirectory folder in URL using .htaccess and get redirected to the intended files

Tags: php

I have the following URL:https://www.bidhaa.net/scripts/details I managed to remove .php extension using .htaccess Now, I need to remove scripts folder in URL and get redirected to the intended files in scripts folder so that URL become https://www.bidhaa.net/details

Answer (score 0):

Try To add this code on your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^scripts/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

i found the answer from this link, maybe this will help
[Remove directory from URL with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668612/remove-directory-from-url-with)

Comment: I managed to remove scripts folder on URL with this answer, but now i get "page not found error" when i try to navigate to the files found in scripts folder.