# 301 Redirect from /page-190454.html‎ TO /190454.html‎

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

i want Redirect all my website links

from old links like this `/page-190454.html‎`

to new links like `/190454.html`

Thnx ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess 301 redirect of single page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421068/htaccess-301-redirect-of-single-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page-([0-9]+)\.html$ /$1.html
```

or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)\.html$ /$1.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thnx code works very good .. if i want Redirect Redirect like /page-tablet-inar.html‎ to /900.html‎ , i try ^page-([A-Z]+)\.html$ but not worked , Thanks again

Comment: @o6qr where does the `900` come from? You want your regex to be `^page-([^/.]+)\.html$`

Comment: i understand , i want Redirect all links Which contain letters and symbols same /page-tablet-inar.html‎ to same link /900.html , i try this ^page-([^/.]+)\.html$ but not worked , thnx

Comment: @o6qr Not sure what that has to do with your original question, as it seems to be two completely different things and won't work together at all, but... `RedirectMatch 301 ^/page-([^/.]+)\.html$ /900.html`

Comment: yes you are right sir @jon that's not my original question , You gave me the solution about it and works very very good thnx .. But I have too old links contain letters not I want to lose it and I want to convert it to new link , i try this code and worked good , thnx sir so much

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read [THIS](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file?) which explains how to redirect a site using htaccess.

Also, it might be simpler using PHP:

```
<?
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.new-url.com" ); 
?>
```

in htaaccess it is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please REPLACE www.newdomain.com in the above code with your actual domain name.

Comment: thnx so much , i try htaccess code but not working give me wrong link 404

Comment: Did you put the php on the original web location then redirected to the other location? Also obviously replace newurl.com with your website name

Comment: sure i replace website name and original web location Does not exist , Thank you for your interest I've found the solution at the top