# redirect single url with query .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have url http://www.somepage.com?value%5b%5d=0_13240 , when i try to use RedirectPermanent, it is not working.

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://www.somepage.com?value%5b%5d=0_13240 http://www.somepage.com/newpage.php
```

i know that is query string in url problem, but i dont know how to write in .htaccess

i tried solutions from here, but nobody uses query in string:
[.htaccess 301 redirect of single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421068/htaccess-301-redirect-of-single-page)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match QUERY_STRING using `RedirectMatch` directive. Use `mod_rewrite` rules instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^value[]=0_13240$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /newpage.php? [L,R=301]
```