# 301 redirect HTTPS to HTTP for a single page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I currently have a SSL certificate applied to my site and ALL URLs redirect to https correctly. I need one of the URLS to be HTTP. I have the following code in my .htaccess that redirects all pages to HTTPS.

I would like the following URL below to be HTTP and NOT HTTPS.

```
http://www.example.com/blog_rss.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^blog_rss.php etc...`?

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Comment: your rule matches everything. mine only matches if the requested url is blog_rss.php. And for such a simple redirect, you don't need to use mod_rewrite. a simple `Redirect Permanent /blog_rss.php http://etc...` would do just as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess 301 redirect of single page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421068/htaccess-301-redirect-of-single-page)

Comment: If I just use a simple redirect for the particular page only. Example: Redirect 301 /blog_rss.php http:// www.example.com/blog_rss.php It causes a redirect loop since I have a global redirect to https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your current code by this one in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog_rss\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(blog_rss\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

---

EDIT: looks like `%{HTTPS}` is not recognized on some servers, which is causing an infinite loop.

Try with `%{SERVER_PORT}` (if default http port is still 80 and ssl port is 443)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog_rss\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(blog_rss\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

You could also try with your initial syntax

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog_rss\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(blog_rss\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your response but when I replace my current code with yours I receive an error. "The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete." Do I replace {HTTP_HOST} with my domain name?

Comment: No you don't have to replace it, this code should work with a copy/paste. It seems you have other rules trying to redirect or maybe it's a cache problem (try with a new browser or clear your browser cache)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I removed all other redirects except for yours and tried it with a new browser/cleared cache but still same result. My goal is to setup a global redirect for all pages to be HTTPS except for blog_rss.php. I hope that was clear in my original posting.

Comment: That's what my code does (tested and working), your original post was clear enough. Is your htaccess in root level ? You must try only with my code (at least right now)

Comment: Yes my .htaccess is in the root. I literally deleted my entire .htaccess file, replaced it with your code, used a new browser, cleared my cache and the result is "This webpage has a redirect loop" The only URL I can access is example.com/blog_rss.php and it redirects to HTTPS.

Comment: So `http://example.com/blog_rss.php` redirects to `https://example.com/blog_rss.php` and `https://example.com/blog_rss.php` stays unchanged ? That's a good point. For the redirect loop, i don't understand since my code **can't** provide such a behaviour. For other than `blog_rss.php`, if it's `http` then it goes to `https` equivalent, that's all. Try to look at http headers to check where it wants to redirect in infinite loop (or give me url and i'll check myself)

Comment: I made a mistake, after I entered your code, I can access blog_rss.php through HTTP or HTTPS. No redirect is happening. Would you be willing to talk to me privately on Google+ or Skype and I can provide the URL? The reason being is that it's a client website and I don't want to leave the site broken for a long period of time.

Comment: Before everything, could you put my code again in your htaccess and give me the url ? This way i'll check http headers and search for errors. If problem persists then we'll have a private discussion

Comment: Sure...code was added to .htaccess. Website is helmerlegal.com. Thanks so much Justin!

Comment: Hi Justin. Did you have a chance to look? I'm just getting kind of worried because I can't have a client website offline for a long period of time.

Comment: Hi Justin. I really really appreciate your help but I can't keep the website offline for more than an hour. That's why I was hoping to chat with you privately when it's a good time for you to test the code and not have to leave the website offline for a long period of time when I don't know if you have had time to look at it or not.

Comment: Yep, i did test, thank you. There's an infinite loop but i can see only one reason (see my edited answer)

Comment: I used the second code that included the initial syntax and IT WORKED! You are a life safer! Thank you so much Justin!

Comment: I have used the code it's not working for me. I'm in same situation, I need to navigate http to https all pages except one particular url, ex if user https://www.example.com/index.php/C_booking/book this need to redirect http://www.example.com/index.php/C_booking/book. RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule ^book http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [QSA,L] I have tried this code but not working