# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP for a single page in wordpress (no .php file for page)

Tags: wordpress, http, redirect, https

Having read this topic:
[301 redirect HTTPS to HTTP for a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455985/301-redirect-https-to-http-for-a-single-page) 
and haven't solved it out because I don't have in my wordpress theme a .php file for every page since the pages are saved in the database. I have the following code in my .htaccess file that redirects my site to https.
So I would like the following URL below to be HTTP and NOT HTTPS.
In that url I want to load a flash game from another site using a plugin if that helps. I am not a code expert so please help me out here.

Thanks

```
    http://www.example.com/fun-page


   # BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[2.4.1]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Note that if not all your webpage aren't https, you can't use HSTS, which is the ONLY protection against MITM.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for but what about adding the game into the iFrame?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess 301 redirect for all https to http EXCEPT ONE PAGE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079015/htaccess-301-redirect-for-all-https-to-http-except-one-page)

Comment: My webpage is https.. The game is added in the html with a shortcode.