# How to redirect a single page from https to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've redirect my website to https but I've need it to redirect a single page from https to http.

My rules to redirect to https are:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What rule I might use to redirect a single page to http?

Comment: That question is asked again and again. Always it turns out that the better thing to do is fix the reason _why_ you want to redirect instead of actually making your service insecure or broken.

Comment: @arkascha because in this page I need use an external widget that not works with ssl

Comment: Yep, including external stuff is the usual cause of such attempts. Bit that won't work by a redirection, the browser will refuse to follow such a redirection. You need to proxy that resource via you service instead.

Answer (score 0):

I looked and here's an answer from a couple of years ago with a similar problem.  This code works according to the comments:

Try with %{SERVER_PORT} (if default http port is still 80 and ssl port is 443)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog_rss\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(blog_rss\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Original question/answers at:  [301 redirect HTTPS to HTTP for a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455985/301-redirect-https-to-http-for-a-single-page)

Comment: This won't work for an external widget embedded in a page. All browsers will refuse to follow such a redirection for very good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

First your code will not catch none `wwww`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# the first two lines above will catch all http request so , nothing will 
# pass to the following 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Make your code like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^   https://www.yoursite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

to exclude spacific page add this

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/your/path/to/pages$ 
 RewriteRule ^   https://www.yoursite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** clear your browser cache and test it.

> update:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} my-page [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^   http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Try this , it means catch any request contains `https` & your page then force into `http`

Comment: sorry i missed % before %{REQUEST_URI} try it now

Comment: it still not works. I use Drupal https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/.htaccess and I've follow this https://www.drupalaid.com/blog/how-to-quickly-add-ssl-to-your-drupal-site to add https redirect

Comment: but still your original code will force any http into https regardless of www is it there or not

Comment: believe me it should work try to save your all file  outside and clear your browser cache then  put only the code that forces https then my code. does your file in main root or where give the path ?

Comment: thank you for help but still not works. this is my .htaccess in main root: https://pastebin.com/MJAJU9ar

Comment: the only proplem right now he doesnt exclude your page right ? does it in root ?

Comment: wait i read your htaccess you put the file without extension , add it and clear browser cache and test it?  change this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-page$ to this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-page.php$

Comment: with this https://pastebin.com/MJAJU9ar the page that I would exclude is not loaded. Instead if I remove the rules that I report in my first post the redirect to http of the page that I would exclude is forced but when I back to another page the redirect to https is not forced

Comment: I use a CMS with path alias, the pages are not extension

Comment: change RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-page$ to this RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} my-page [NC]