# 301 Redirect not working (WordPress) - [ Probler with ?m=1 in URL ]

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have very weird problem.

My WordPress site gets traffic to the same page with different additional parameters.

**Example:**

```
mysite.com/page1.html?m=1 
mysite.com/page1.html
```

It is the same page, but **?m=1** makes WP show 404 error page.

I tried 301 redirect like this (in actual HTACCESS file i also use *http://* but here I cannot):

```
Redirect 301 /page1.html?m=1  mysite.com/page1.html
```

But this does not do anything.

Traffic comes from google, so I cannot change this URL structure - I have to work with what I got ... So how I fix this???

It could be either WP or HTACCESS problem ... I searched and cannot find anything - i get results for M1 rifle :(

**Please help - this is a live site**

Answer (score 3):

You can't match against the query string in mod_alias's `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch`. You need to use mod_rewrite's `%{QUERY_STRING}` or `%{THE_REQUEST}` variables. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect any request that has the "m=1" query string and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page1.html?m=1$ /page1.html
```

Try that see also this answer [.htaccess 301 redirect of single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421068/htaccess-301-redirect-of-single-page)

Comment: Thanks @1Bladesforhire - what if i have multiple pages? Can I create single rule for all?

Comment: It depends on if they have a matching pattern. if they all end in ?m=1$ then you could.