# 302 Redirect php || Step by Step

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, indexing, ranking

As per your forms i understand process given below: Please correct me if something wrong.

i need to change www.domian.com/About.php to www.domian.com/about.php

step 1 i need to create about.php file

step 2 i need to put code :  Redirect 301 /About.php " www.domian.com/about.php" code in htacess file.

step3 i need to define canonical tag in about.php

Now after that in future i want to make change only in about.php . also can i delete About.php because we are not using it ? Please correct me if something is incorrect .

Comment: Yes, the .htaccess file doesn't require the actual file to be present in this case.

Comment: also <link rel="canonical" href=" www.domian.com/about.php" " /> does i need to put it in about.php please check its correct or not

Comment: @VinaySharma if you put a redirect you don't need the canonical link. You would have needed it if you were just rewriting.

Comment: I am just changing About.php to about.php renaming it ....but google indexed About.php i need to change it for total 65 pages .

Comment: i think there is a similar discussion on: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421068/htaccess-301-redirect-of-single-page]

Comment: ok as per this post  step 1 i need to create pages in lowercase step 2 redirect in .htaccess step3 delete uppercase file. is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to use the `.htaccess` to redirect users. It will be hard if you do so.

I would suggest you entering the following code to the PHP file to redirect users:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Redirecting you to *The Website*</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="<Your website>" />
</head>
<?php
# The code below will redirect the users to the site that you want to redirect to.
# If the site has HTTPs, please change the "http://" to "https://"
header('Location: http://*Where you want the users to be redirected to*/');
exit();
# The "exit" code will prevent any more redirects in the current page.
?>
</html>
```

One example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Redirecting you to GhostAnti DDoS</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://fantomnet.cf/" />
</head>
<?php
# The code below will redirect the users to the site that you want to redirect to.
# If the site has HTTPs, please change the "http://" to "https://"
header('Location: https://ghostantiddos.com/');
exit();
# The "exit" code will prevent any more redirects in the current page.
?>
</html>
```

Hope that helped. Hit me up if you still need help in this

Comment: What does it mean                                                                                  <link rel="canonical" href="www.domian.com/about.php" /> in about.php

Comment: It is defining a canonical tag inside that file; since you wanted to define it.