# How to add "-" hyphen with some text using htaccess in url

Tags: .htaccess

I need help in redirecting a url with adding some text with a hyphen.

Following is what I want to achieve:

I want to redirect https://somesite.com/girl-dresses/singapore to https://somesite.com/female-dresses/singapore-city

I tried:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> Redirect 301 /girl-dresses/singapore https://somesite.com/female-dresses/singapore-city

But this doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess 301 redirect of single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421068/htaccess-301-redirect-of-single-page)

Answer (score 0):

Try add in .htaccess (high is possible) this rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^girl-dresses\/singapore$ /female-dresses/singapore-city [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately it didn't work, url comes out to be https://somesite.com/female-dresses/singapore, city isn't added to it.